# GLFW Problem "The driver does not appear to support OpenGL"

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

I am trying to learn OpenGL & GLFW , when I run this simple project
I get error ID : "65542" with the message "The driver does not appear to support OpenGL".

My graphics card is an old & cheap Intel 64MB

Comment: Googling the error suggests that you need to update your graphics drivers. Have you done that?

Comment: no i think i'am still using Basic VGA

Comment: Then updating your drivers would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: yeah i will do , did i have to download & install opengl or coming with drivers

Comment: There's no specific download or installation for OpenGL, the graphics drivers provide the implementation.

Comment: thank you brother :)

Comment: @OuchaneCC If Tyyppi's answer doesn't work, try adding a new version of `opengl32.dll` to your .exe's directory (assuming your on Windows). It can be found online. Usually this is located in System32 directory, but since you have an older graphics card it may not. I don't recommend just throwing it into the System32 directory since there is a chance (very tiny chance) that it has malware of sorts on it, so this mitigates the risk

Comment: @Jason Thank you